# how to set datetime type index for weekly column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a data as given below:

```
date    product price   amount
201901  A   10  20
201902  A   10  20
201903  A   20  30
201904  C   40  50
```

This data is saved in test.txt file.
Date column is given as a weekly column as a concatenation of year and weekid. I am trying to set the date column as an index, with given code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t", parse_dates=['date'])
```

But it gives an error. How can I set the date column as an index with datetime type?

Comment: What error it gives? can you post your test.txt content?

Answer (score 0):

Use `index_col` parameter for setting `index`:

```
data=pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t", index_col=[0])
```

**EDIT:** Using column name as index:

```
data=pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t", index_col=['date'])
```

For converting `index` from `int` to `date time`, do this:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%Y%m')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. Is there any way to do this with column name? The order of the column might change, so it is safer for me to use column name.

Comment: The "date" column is assigned as int. I am trying to assign it dateTimeIndex. Please consider it too. Thank you.

Comment: @user3104352 try `data=pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t", index_col=['date'])` if you want to assign index name instead of integer. Also your date column is in `Year-Weekid` format right ?

Comment: yes, I am trying to get Year-Weekid format. But if I use this line, data=pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t", index_col=['date']), it assigns the int to date index column.

Comment: @user3104352 I've updated my answer as per your comments. Check the `EDIT` part.

Answer (score 0):

There might be simpler solutions than this too, using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) first I converted your `Year-Weekid` into `Year-month-day` format and then just simply used [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to make `date` as index column.

```
import pandas as pd

data ={
    'date' : [201901,201902,201903,201904,201905],
    'product' : ['A','A','A','C','C'],
    'price' : [10,10,10,20,20],
    'amount' : [20,20,30,50,60]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# str(x)+'1' converts to Year-WeekId-Weekday, so 1 represents `Monday` so 2019020 
# means 2019 Week2 Monday.
# If you want you can try with other formats too

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)+'1',format='%Y%W%w'))
df.set_index(['date'],inplace=True)
df
```

**Edit:**

To see datetime in `Year-WeekID` format you can style the dataframe as follows, however if you set `date` as index column following code won't be able to work. And also remember following code just applies some styling so just useful for display purpose only, internally it will remain as date-time object.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)+'1',format='%Y%W%w'))
style_format = {'date':'{:%Y%W}'}
df.style.format(style_format)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your responce but I need to keep the format of  "Year-WeekId". Is there any solution to set datetime type to date column while keeping the format?

Comment: @user3104352 in my solution the column type is in `datetime`, I am not aware of `Year-Week` formatting as general `datetime` is in `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` kind of formats. However you can access the week and year easily while processing values as that column is in `datetime` format. Something like `(df.index).week` and `(df.index).year` should work while accessing week and year.

Comment: @user3104352 I have edited my answer, please do check it.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the `date_parser` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m')

inputtxt = StringIO("""date    product price   amount
201901  A   10  20
201902  A   10  20
201903  A   20  30
201904  C   40  50""")

df = pd.read_csv(inputtxt, sep='\s+', parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)
df.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------   --------------  -----         
 0   date     4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   product  4 non-null      object        
 2   price    4 non-null      int64         
 3   amount   4 non-null      int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 256.0+ bytes
```